# Multiplier is locked when I try to make percentage constraints

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to make a percentage constraint to make that my layouts will adapt to any device but when I try to change `Multiplier` value it is locked as you can see in the image below:

[image]

How can I unlock it to put a different `Multiplier` value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you make width only constraint.

You have to specify your constraint as example: `button.width == superView.width` with multiplayer.

[image: Visial effect]

Drag you contentView into parentView. Drag with Control from contentView to parentView and tap `Equal Widths`. Next change multiplayer to that one you want.

Comment: How can I do it visually?

Comment: If I look on my tree, I can see a dropdown on my `TextView` that has `width = 300` and `height = 100` and another dropdown with `Constraints` group (as yours) with some other constraints. I guess that I should move `Constraints` on `TextView` to the `Constraints`group, right?

Comment: You added constraint only for your TextView, But you should make this constraint between textView and superView. Remove constraints from your TextView. Next hold Control key and drag line from your TextView to parentView and tap Equal Widths/Heights (depend what you want achieve). You will be able to change multiplier than.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your last comment give the clue about how to connect my `UITextField` with the `SuperView`.

Answer (score 0):

Your current constraint is `self.width = x` It doesn't make sense to have a multiplier in that equation. Try control clicking between your view and the view you want it to scale with, and choose 'Equal Widths'. Then you will be able to use the multiplier `self.width = multiplier * targetView.width + constant`